# Bootstrap Grid with 6 Columns breaks at 4 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I never have had a problem with the bootstrap grid until recently. The problem that I am having is with the medium breakpoint. On xs I have 2 columns, on small I have 3 columns, on medium I want 4 columns but this is broken and on large I have 6 columns. I am ending up with a row of 4 and then a row of 2, and so on and so forth.

- xs: 6*6 = 36
- sm: 4*6 = 24
- md: 3*6 = 18 <- 18 is obviously why its causing the problem
- lg: 2*6 = 12

For some reason I cannot think of a solution to this problem. The example can be seen at http://dev.charliegrove.com/kingdom

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
</div>
```

Any advice greatly appreciated as I always use bootstrap and figure there must be something I am missing here to accomplish this!!? Thank you

Comment: I checked the demo and its working fine. You know that **bootstrap** works on the screen resolution. Check your screen resolution and if you use firebug then try to inspect the element and see which class is applied. For higher resolution testing you can change the browse resolution by `ctrl + --`

Comment: When you scale it down, you dont see it break to have a row of 4 then a row of 2 then another row of 4 ect. Its from 1199px browser width to 994px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I show your demo code and you have code like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
</div>
```

Now here the problem is, in each `<div class="row"></div>` you have 6 other divs, an you have repeated this format. So when the child divs set in the row, its break down to the new line for the next `<div class="row"></div>`. So in the `col-md-3` class it will break down in the set of 4 and 2.

To avoid this problem you can set all your child divs in the single `<div class="row"></div>` like this :

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 home-tile-holder"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats perfect! I was confused I guess on what the point of the .row div was even for!

Answer (score 1):

I see two simple options... either skip the md-3 columns (i.e. go straight from sm-4 to lg-2), or as @tejashoni suggested, put all your squares in a single `div class="row"`

Comment: Thanks, your totally right, in this case I dont want to skip the md-3 so having them all in one row is perfect. I dont really see the value in even having multiple rows anymore containing the columns. Just one row even if there are hundreds of columns sounds like the way to do it.

Comment: Totally. I'm sure they are still useful in some circumstances, but I've never come across one.